# How do I fix this rigging issue on a character?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

So I have been using Blender for a bit, but this is my first rigging project. I knew this was going to be uncharted territories, so I looked up some guides. After feeling comfortable with the process, I tried it out on my first character. I know this character has a lot of issues, but I said why not, its part of learning. I applied the rig, parented it to the character and moved it around to check. I noticed a small issue as I moved around the character. There is some clipping issue because I got lazy in the past and didn't fully create a body under the clothes (I couldn't find a good way to make clothes back then, and kinda still can't). So is there a way to fix this? I'll post the pictures. In it, you can see that the hand when rotated is obviously hollow. This is more of a learning thing, as I am really new to the rigging scene. I know its a rookie mistake to be lazy, so any ideas would be appreciated. I'm using v2.83.3

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think I figured it out. I'll try attaching the vertices to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Merging the vertices worked. Just went to a previous save, and merged the vertices via edit mode for each object.